# Complex Group By Query (recursive?)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

sorry for the title but I'm not sure how I should call it. I'm using PostgreSQL 8.3 and would be fine with non-ansi query proposals.

Suppose this schema:

```
TimeEntries
id              - int
entry_date      - date
tracked_seconds - int
project_id      - int

projects
id              - int
name            - string
path            - string
```

Projects are hirachical, I don't care about parent_id etc. instead I opted for the path column, example:

```
Renovate Home    - path = renovate-home
- Clean Kitchen  - path = renovate-home/clean-kitchen
```

I want a query that returns the following:

```
date - project_path - tracked_seconds(this project) - tracked_seconds (total of self and child projects)
```

Grouped by date and multiple times per project path so example data:

```
projects
name          path
Funny         funny
- Project     funny/project
-- Is Funny   funny/project/is-funny
Foo           foo
- Bar         foo/bar
```

If there are now TimeEntries for funny/project and foo/bar and i Issue this query:

```
SELECT         entry_date, p.path as project_path, sum(tracked_seconds) / 60
FROM           time_entries te
LEFT JOIN      projects p on te.project_id = p.id
GROUP BY       entry_date, p.path
```

I get this result:

```
entry_date        project_path           ?sum?
2010-10-01        funny/project          20
2010-10-01        foo/bar                10
```

What I want is this:

```
entry_date        project_path           direct_sum     total
2010-10-01        funny                  0              20
2010-10-01        funny/project          20             20 
2010-10-01        foo                    0              10
2010-10-01        foo/bar                10             10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you stuck with 8.3 or can you upgrade to 8.4?

Because with 8.4, I think this could be solved using windowing functions:

```
SELECT te.entry_date, 
       te.tracked_seconds, 
       p.path, 
       sum(tracked_seconds) over (partition by (string_to_array(path, '/'))[1] order by entry_date asc, path desc)
FROM TimeEntries te
 JOIN projects p ON te.project_id = p.id
ORDER BY entry_date
```

Answer (score 0):

This query ought to get you closer to your goal:

```
SELECT         entry_date, p.path as project_path, p2.path, sum(tracked_seconds) / 60
FROM           time_entries te
LEFT JOIN      projects p on te.project_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN      projects p2 on p2.path LIKE p.path + '/%'
GROUP BY       entry_date, p.path, p2.path
```

Comment: This is what I also came up with, still I'd have to filter it in my app and that could be done with project_path alone. Anyways thanks for the effort

Comment: just a quick note: + does not work for character concatenation in standard SQL (and thus it does not work in PostgreSQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks, I'd not realised that.  It barely works in T-SQL, I have to say - more often that not I have to coerce one value or another to a string in order to get it to not try to convert a string to e.g. an integer.